# Copy all databases with data from a server to another existing server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have a server say **TestServer1** with lots of databases. I want to copy all **databases**, **views**, **stored procedures**, **functions** with all data to another server say **TestServer2**. How can I do it quickly, easily and with less effort.

What i can think is to copy each database as script / copy the .mdf,.ldf files and attach them to new server. But its time consuming and irritating. Can anyone help me with a efficient way?

**For Info**, I am copying from **SQLSERVER 2005** to **SQLServer 2012**.

**Please let me know, why you guys think this is not a proper question. Just dont downvote carelessly.**

Comment: How many is lots of databases? The quickest way is to copy the MDF's and LDF's yes, but it is manual work. The backup restore is your best option, but there is a step missing. You need the copy the backup to the new server on C:\Temp first before you can restore it. Another problem is compatibility from 2005 and 2012. Please read up about this.

Comment: 123 databases, 66 stored procedures, 17 views, 45  functions. And I am trying to copy them all at a time. Yes, I am studuing on Version comaptibilty.

Comment: Sorry, 123 databases, 66 sp's, views and functions, but no tables? Do you mean 123 Tables? And secondly, is this going to be a one time thing?

Comment: :P... 123 database, yes. and each database contains 6-15 tables. no, i didn't mean 123 tables. And yesm I am trying to do it in a easy way.

Answer (score 1):

try backing up and restoring as described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190436.aspx

or write two simple scripts from your database, much like this:

```
SELECT 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + name 
       + ' TO DISK=''c:\temp\' + name + '.bak''' 
FROM   sys.databases 
WHERE  name NOT IN ( 'master', 'msdb', 'tempdb' ) 

SELECT 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + name 
       + ' FROM DISK=''c:\temp\' + name + '.bak''' 
FROM   sys.databases 
WHERE  name NOT IN ( 'master', 'msdb', 'tempdb' )
```

which you can then use to backup / restore your databases.

Comment: i can backup each database individually. Is there a way to do it at once?

Comment: You can write a script to back up and restore all the databases at once, but That would also be "time consuming and irritating", as you put it.

Comment: i have understood your technique and working on it. and already backed up all databases with a cursor :) @Brett Schneider

Comment: This is the best way to do it. Just remember to copy the backup to the new server first before you restore the database. You can use `SELECT 'XCOPY c:\temp\'+name+'.bak \\server2\c$\temp\' +name+'.bak''' FROM sys.databases
where name not in ('master', 'msdb', 'tempdb', 'model')`